# Is "Sign in with Apple" mandatory for older iOS version?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

We are about to release a new application to the store, that's target is down to iOS 10. As we have Facebook and Google sign-in, according to the new [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple), we must provide an Apple Sign In option. It is mandatory. But it is not clear to me if this is required only for applications from iOS 13 and above, or it is **mandatory** to be included also for lower iOS versions, possibly using the [Sign in with Apple JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs).

Comment: Your application targets iOS 10 - but it also works in iOS 10+ as well. So, in my perspective, it requires you to have Apple Sign In (if you have any other login that falls into their requirements) for any new upload. I think the SDK to apply Apple Sign In requires iOS 12+, so, you would probably need to make a version "if available" and deal with it in those scenarios.

Comment: I concluded the same, but could not find any official documentation that would affirm that. But most probably will implement it for lower iOS version also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will be required to have 'sign in with Apple' as of **April 2020**, and if your app has any other sign in methods (Like Google), then most Apple reviewers will push it back anyway and enforce that you have it.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple

Are the guidelines for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per apple if your app uses any of the other social sign in such as google,facebook, amazon etc you are required to provide apple sign in as an option to the users. April 2020 is the marked deadline for now.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple

Also if your app requires, you to send emails to the user you might want to invest some time into how private email relay service works.